# Guava's policy based caching

Tags: java, caching, guava

I'm trying to create a simple session cache that allows me to set a maximum size on the whole cache.  The cache is not a computing cache, so I think Guava's `CacheBuilder` with a `LoadingCache` is not appropriate.  I want to be able perform the following operations:

`get(key)` data from the cache that was previously stashed during a stashing operation
`put(key,value)` into the cache during the stashing operation

I tried using MapMaker but the maximum size method seems to be antiquated.  Does anyone know what options I have?  I can always resort to just using a simple Map and rolling my own policy I suppose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The cache is not a computing cache, so I think Guava's `CacheBuilder` with a `LoadingCache` is not appropriate.

So use the `CacheBuilder` without it. It works exactly the same, except that you call plain `build()` instead if `build(CacheLoader)`. Everything stays the same, except for you get a "normal" cache instead of a loading one. That's all.

> I tried using MapMaker but the maximum size method seems to be antiquated.

Caching via `MapMaper` will go away one day, forget it.

---

The example is very trivial, just create

```
private final static Cache<String, String> cache =
    CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(123).build();
```

and then try this:

```
cache.put("a", "A");
cache.put("b", "B");
System.out.println(cache.getIfPresent("a"));
for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) cache.put("n" + i, "x");
System.out.println(cache.getIfPresent("a"));
```